# How to change default caption color of group box in MFC programmatically?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, colors, groupbox

Currently groupboxs in my application shows caption in blue color in Windows xp and black in windows 7. How to change default caption color of group box in MFC programmatically? so that it can be shown in black color in both Windows XP and Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [OnCtlColor().](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wwk06hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) MFC will call this before it draws the control to allow you to set the brushes.

Comment: I tried OnCtlColor as below,              if( nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_STATIC)
 {
  pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
  pDC->SetTextColor(BLACK);
  pDC->SetDCPenColor(BLACK);
 }

 return CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);            But there is no effect.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this works with XP themes. You will need to turn off theme support with SetWindowTheme().